# c# Winfoms: How to execute some code after extender provider constructor has been executed

Tags: c#, winforms, components, iextenderprovider

I need to perform some operations after extender provider constructor has been executed in run-time. Is there any way to do this?

**UPDATE**:

What really happens to me is that I am not able to get the values that user set in design time for the public properties that extender provider provides.

For example, in design time from Visual Studio user set a value of 200 for AlphaChannel property. Then It runs the application, and in run-time, if I request AlphaChannel property from within both constructors it is 0. Once constructors has been executed, if I request AlphaChannel property again, for example, from within the timer tick event, I get the correct value, 200. So I would like to get this value once constructors are executed in order to initialize some variables that later they are used within timer tick event but I do not want to get the correct value and initialize the variables later used from the timer tick event so is there a place where I can get these values?

Below a piece of code:

```
public class MyProvider : Component, IExtenderProvider
{
    public MyProvider()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer_Tick);
    }

    public MyProvider(IContainer container)
        : this()
    {
        container.Add(this);
    }

    private Timer timer;
    private byte alphaChannel;

    [DefaultValue(255)]
    public byte AlphaChannel
    {
        get { return this.alphaChannel; }
        set { this.alphaChannel = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code that you already have? To avoid getting out-of-context answers.

Comment: @IanH. It simple. I have a constructor for the extender provider, and I need to execute some initialization after constructor is being executed. Some kind of event that detected when constructor has been executed or provided loaded but extender provider has no events to handle.

Comment: Why not just call your initialization at the end of your constructor?

Comment: @IanH. Yes, this is what I am trying to do but at the end of the constructor where? once constructor has been executed? the problem I have is that my provider provides some properties that user can set. So user set these properties, but the values set by the user, has no effect after the constructor has been executed. If I try to read these properties values set by user within the constructor, in this moment, they are not available.

Comment: @IanH. I have updated my post to show more in details what's going on.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, I have Getx and Setx public methods, also CanExtend (not shown here).  I am not referring to these parameters that user sets on the component that provider applies to. I am referring to the provider parameters.

Comment: @HansPassant For example, you drag and drop the provider to your form, and this provider object has some properties, you can view them on its properties window.I am referring to these properties, provider properties, in my case AlphaChannel. These parameters are set globally for all components the provider is applied to. I am not referring to the GetX and SetX methods.